# How to disable a html page refresh with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function, but I want to disable the refresh of the page.. I have I button and when I click it it shows the second form and hide the first one... But it shows the second form just for a second, and then display the first form again. I think it is reloading the page...But is there any way to stop it..
this is my function

```
 function displayform2() {
     /*For desktop*/
     var inputs = [
         document.getElementById('firstname1'),
         document.getElementById('lastname1'),
         document.getElementById('cel1'),
         document.getElementById('email1'),
     ];
     var nr = 0; /*to keep the number of fields empty*/
     for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
         if (inputs[i].value == '') {
             nr++;
         }
     if (document.getElementById('desktop1').style.display == 'block') {
         if (nr > 0) {
             document.getElementById('totalfield1').style.display = 'block';
         } else {
             document.getElementById('desktop1').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('desktop2').style.display = 'block';
             document.getElementById('desktop3').style.display = 'none';
         }
     }
```

HTML

```
  <input type="button" value="Proceed"  id="submit1" onclick="displayform2()" class="button" style=" margin-top: -40px;margin-left: 60%;width: 25%" disabled>
```

I am using these button

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Show us the HTML.  Are you using an anchor to call the displayform2() function?

If so, make sure to use return false; to prevent the default behaviour (which is to navigate)

```
<a href="javascript:displayform2(); return false;">Display form</a>
```

Comment: I am using a button like above

Comment: Thanks a lot...It function now  :)

Comment: Good to know :-)  Could you please upvote my answer (hey, I'm collecting points!)